# generate common tests for django

Tags: django, testng, smoke-testing

I'm developing sites on django I'm think what most problems may be found by using smoke coverage tests method. But (in most cases) write the tests to check response code is 200 for every app, every view, and every url is so bored (e.g. when you are develop few sites parallel). I have a question: How can I automate this process, may be exist some complete solutions to generate some common tests for django.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use sublimetext you can make custom snippets, to generate those tests. More about snippets here http://courses.tutsplus.com/courses/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-2